# Is there a character in Linux that can be used at start of a filename to bump it to the top in regular sort order but doesn't require escaping etc?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

There are lots of questions/answers explaining what characters one shouldn't use in Linux filenames etc.

I am looking for a non-alpha/numeric character that I can put at the front of a filename to bump it to the top of an ls without requiring escape characters to handle it on the command line.

In macOS I use <Filename> to sort in the GUI, but the < is not good on the command line, of course, one needs to escape it as appropriate. Similarly -Filename- doesn't work well on the command line.

Is there one special character, coming before all alpha-numeric characters, that doesn't have a special meaning for (most) shells?

Or are all the early-sorting characters taken? :-( :-)

Thanks,
Ashley.

PS I've seen 111- used, but that doesn't sit right with me...

Comment: If 'regular sort order' means the ASCII collation sequence (usually selected by `LC_COLLATE=C`), then `#` or `%` are likely the safest characters.  The ASCII character set has the punctuation characters before numbers and letters, but most of them require escaping/quoting to be safe on the command line for most shells.

Comment: @SottoVoce `#` needs to be quoted in Zsh, which leaves `%`.

Comment: Unfortunately, default (after installation) sort ordering on Ubuntu seems to be en_AU.UTF-8 for me, and ordering to ignore non-alpha/numeric characters when sorting.

Comment: You can [temporarily] use `LANG=C` and/or `LC_ALL=C` in the command line where you sort, and that way get reliable results. Make it convenient with aliases for the commands you intend to use.

Comment: @AshleyAitken, with `en_AU.UTF-8` I think `0` 'zero' is a good choice to get into the top of the boot order.

Comment: By analogy with `.` (dot files, hidden) I use comma `,`. It is on the adjacent key, unshifted, no special significance, and does not intrude on the following characters.

Comment: Thanks @Paul_Pedant, a good suggestion, but with en_AU.UTF-8 language, the sort ordering seems to ignore it. I'd prefer not to have to change language.

Comment: If this is only for `ls`, declare `alias ls='LC_ALL=C ls '`  ;-)

Comment: I usually use one or more zeroes and a hyphen or underscore as a filename prefix to force sort order - e.g. `00-README.txt`.   This also allows me to manually order some common things - e.g. `000-README.txt`, `001-TODO.txt`, `002-MISC-NOTES.txt`, etc, or for directory names I want sorted to the top - e.g. `00-A-F/`, `00-G-L/`, etc. I don't typically have filenames beginning with punctuation, so this works in most cases with the locales I use. It's not 100% perfect but since I don't rely on it in scripts, it's good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing it, you've asked two very complicated questions...  quoting and sorting.

Sort order is determine by locale.  What comes first is... not fixed.

e.g.

```
$ touch Hello hello There there
$ LANG=C ls -1
Hello
There
hello
there
$ LANG=en_US ls -1
hello
Hello
there
There
```

The next is the quoting question.  This is very shell dependent.  So in my standard shell (ksh99) the `!` is a good character.  But this fails in `bash`.

```
$ ls
!README  0  1  2  a  b  c
$ cat !README
hello
$ bash
bash-4.2$ cat !README
bash: !README: event not found
```

If we work our way through the ASCII sequence, the first "useful" character might be a `+`.  This does not appear to be a special character in ksh/bash/zsh/csh.

But since quoting is shell specific *and* it's possible some commands might take a `+` as an argument (historically, `head` did this) we can never be certain.

And, of course, LANG setting can override (so `+` isn't first!).

```
% LANG=en_US ls -1
0
1
2
a
b
c
+hello
```

So, in general... there's no specific character that is guaranteed to come first.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I had my hopes up with + but as you say it seems to be ignored in sorting, although I know it depends on the language... mine seems to be set to en_AU.UTF-8 by default from installation (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

The sort order of `ls` depends on command line options and language setting. If your LANG variable is set to a natural language, chances are that special characters like %, _, -, + or : (none of which need to be escaped for Bash) are simply ignored. This is the case for LANG=en_US.UTF-8, anyway.

However, if LANG is set to C, filenames seem to be sorted based on the ASCII values of their characters, and the above special characters can indeed be used to "bump up" the position of a file in the `ls` output. Example:

```
$ LANG=C ls
%myfile
+myfile
-myfile
:myfile
_myfile
clr-debug-pipe-440205-1575025808-in
clr-debug-pipe-440205-1575025808-out
...
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ls
clr-debug-pipe-440205-1575025808-in
clr-debug-pipe-440205-1575025808-out
dotnet-diagnostic-440205-1575025808-socket
f.py
%myfile
+myfile
-myfile
:myfile
_myfile
...
```

Don't forget that there are command line options that sort based on timestamps, ownership and the like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Most of those characters have special meaning in popular shells, as I am sure you know, except +, which unfortunately, as you also suggest, is ignored in en_AU.UTF-8

Comment: I don't think you would find (m)any popular shells where % - _ : are special. Especially the underscore. But it's true that these symbols seem to be ignored when natural languages are configured (to be honest, I have only tried English). Your workaround or solution is to temporarily set the language to C, as shown.